# Passing Barcode ID to a HTML form as input

Tags: php, android, html

We have many barcode scanners on android like Barcode Scanner, QuickMark etc. Is it possible to map the output of these scanners as input to a HTML form attribute? 
   I am sorry if this is a vague question and it would be a great help. 
Thanks in advance,
sai

Comment: do you want to use scanner and get the value to use in your project? is that your are asking

Answer (score 1):

There is no official standard that will work across all devices/ scanner apps, but the closest is [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) (the makers of [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android)) as its open source and a lot of other barcode scanners use there

The process is described on there [wiki page here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages) : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages

It involves embedding a link in your webpage with the `zxing://` protocol or linking to `http://zxing.appspot.com/`, and setting up a call back for the result.

The `zxing://` method works with both Android and iOS, but the `http://` method does not work on iOS but if you try to follow the `http://` version of the link without the zxing barcode scanner installed your taken to a page that suggests you install it.

Answer (score 0):

A barcode scanner is just a fancy keyboard. We used one recently for a conference check-in system. We found that having the input box focus() on the text field we needed on load was the best way to do it.